# Possibility of a alphabet appearing in a word

Tags: probability

I have a 24 character encrypted string. We store a hex value between 0x00 - 0xFF in each of these 24 characters. We wanted to find the possibility of 00 or 0A (the NULL and the New Line hex values) appearing at least once in this 24 character encrypted string.

For every character the possibility is 2 of 256. Is then the possibility of having at least one 0x00 or one 0x0A in a 24 character string = 128/24 = 5.33,

ie. we will see either 0x00 or 0x0A in every 1 in 5.33 encrypted strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No (especially, probabiiteis can never exceed $1$). The probability of no success is in a single place is $1-\frac2{256} $, hence the probability of no success in any of the $2$ places (assuming the caracters are independant) is $\left(1-\frac2{256}\right)^{24}$. Hence finally the probability of success is $1-\left(1-\frac2{256}\right)^{24}$.

Comment: You are correct. Probability can never exceed 1. Sorry for not being more specific in my question.. Now I changed my question a little bit by changing the word probability to possibility. We want to find the chances that either 0x00 or 0x0A will appear in a word.. something like 1 in 5 words we have a chance to see it..

Comment: I just calculated your answer.. it comes to 0.171.. So it is correct that we can see either 0x00 or 0x0A in 1 in 5.88 words..